# This node is offline because it uses an old slave.jar

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

In Jenkins node it is showing This node is offline because it uses an old slave.jar
In agent machine, executed  `javaws http://xxx/computer/xxx/slave-agent.jnlp` command which is throwing exception.

Jenkins is not upgraded. Other agents are working fine. Facing this issue only in one agent.

Exception screenshot

[image]

[[image: Master machine screenshot]]

Comment: Check if the slave-agent is already running as a Windows service on this machine but is in a hung state. If yes, then stop the service and try running the command again.

Comment: deleted service and i'm able to  run the command but still in master machine  showing as  This node is offline because it uses an old slave.jar. Even deleted completed Jenkins folder installed from the beginning  but issue not resolved.

Comment: Please refer above Master machine screenshot.

Comment: Please also verify the Java versions in both the master and slave machines. A large difference between them could be a reason as well.

Comment: In both master and slave using 1.8 JDK

Comment: out of two slaves with same config connected to master one is working fine the another one is went to offline suddenly. Please help me here to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please try this out https://www.mail-archive.com/jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com/msg04387.html. If this doesn’t work, your last bet will be to delete the agent from the master and add it again, which should be pretty simple to do.

Comment: facing one more issue now from where i can download ReportByJenkin.jar using to consolidate report from 2,3 jobs. Do you have any idea please help me.